# Why are Perl modules case sensitive?

Tags: perl, module, cpan

Although I haven't seen any modules with same name but with different cases, but just for curiosity, I was trying to install [Log::Log4perl](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Log%3a%3aLog4perl) and during installation I misspelled it 'Perl' in place of 'perl':

```
% cpan -i Log::Log4Perl 
Cannot install Log::Log4Perl, don't know what it is.
```

When I used correct name then things went well:

```
% cpan -i Log::Log4perl
```

Same names but different cases can create conflicts. Is there any specific reason behind that?

Comment: It's not so much that perldoc allows it, but it asks the filesystem if a name exists.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because

```
use Foo::Bar;
```

would be ambiguous on case-sensitive file systems (Foo/Bar.pm? foo/bar.pm? FOO/BAR.pm? Foo/Bar.PM? etc), and it would require traversing the directory's contents to find the file's name. (Up to 9 directories per element of `@INC` would need traversing for Foo::Bar.)

Answer (score 11):

In Perl, modules loaded with `use` translated directly onto the file system. Something such as `use Log::Log4perl` translates into:

```
BEGIN {
    require 'Log/Log4perl.pm';
    Log::Log4perl->import;
    }
```

On a system that has a case sensitive file system, if the name is not exactly in the same case, it might as well not even exist. This is explained in the documentation for [use](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) and [require](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html). Different cases mean different names.

As such, when the `cpan` command translates a package name into a distribution, it uses the exact case you specify. The filesystem might be case insensitive, but inside Perl, the package names are still case sensitive. The literal case you enter is the one that Perl (and the `cpan` client) uses. If a package of that exact case isn't defined, the right things won't happen.

I consider this to be one of the major design decisions that hold Perl back and talked about it in my [Frozen Perl 2011 keynote address](http://blogs.perl.org/users/brian_d_foy/2011/03/my-frozen-perl-2011-keynote.html).

Curiously, case insensitive filesystems lets you get away with it, as seen with the [use seems to be case INSENSITIVE!!](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=800770) post on [Perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/).

Comment: Curiously, on windows (one of those case insensitive systems) you can do `use data::dumper` without triggering a fatal error, but it does not load the functions. E.g. `perl -lwe"use data::dumper; print Dumper undef" // 
Name "main::Dumper" used only once: possible typo at -e line 1. // 
print() on unopened filehandle Dumper at -e line 1.`

Comment: @TLP, cause it tries to import from data::dumper, which doesn't have an `import` method.

Comment: @ikegami My point is that trying to `use` a module with the wrong letters causes a fatal error. Using the wrong case does not, but then it does not import the modules methods.

Comment: @TLP, ah, sounded like a question ("Curiously,").

Comment: @ikegami My question would perhaps be how it can seem to load a module withou actually doing it, and why that is not a bug.

Comment: @TLP, It has no way to know what the module should have an import or not, so it has no way to know something went wrong. Now, since Windows is *case-preserving* even though it's case-insensitive, Perl could do a check that actual name of file found is name requested. (Basically, making the file-system case-sensitive.)